# SQL : SELF JOIN Vs RANK, Which will be faster in this scenario?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, join

I'm sure this is a pretty simple SQL query question. This is the model of a table which i am trying to query out the ID with last updated value using the timestamp column (As_Of)

```
ID      Value  As_of

1173    156    20090601

1173    173    20081201

1173    307    20080901

1173    305    20080601

127     209    20090301

127     103    20081201

127     113    20080901

127     113    20080601

1271    166    20090201

1271    172    20081201

1271    170    20080901

1271    180    20080601
...
```

My result should be like this

```
ID      Value    As_of

1173    156      20090601

127     209      20090301

1271    166      20090201
```

Which option should i use to accomplish? Either a SELF JOIN OR RANK()? 
Please suggest me some tips regarding the performance of both approaches. Which is faster? 
I heard SELF JOIN can slow down performance of a query.

RANK():

```
SELECT ID, Value, As_Of, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY As_of DESC) 'RNK'
FROM Table

and by filtering using the column having RANK value 1
```

SELF JOIN :

```
SELECT ID, Value,As_of 
from Table a inner join 
          (SELECT ID, MAX(As_of) as As_of 
          from Table group by ID) b 
on a.ID=b.ID and a.As_of = b.As_of
```

Comment: have you considered benchmarking?

Answer (score 1):

You should try the two approaches on your data to see which is faster.  I might suspect that the `rank()` method would be faster, because it eliminates an explicit `join`, but nothing like a real test can say for sure.

By the way, you should try a third method:

```
select id, value, as_of
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.as_of > t.as_of);
```

Sometimes, this approach can also have good performance.

Answer (score 0):

Cross apply or join works better when you have huge data

```
Select t1.id, t1.value, t1.as_of
from table t
cross apply(Select top 1 * from table t1 where t.id = t1.id order by as_of desc)t1
where t.as_of = t1.as_of
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID,VALUE,AS_OF 
    FROM Table T1 
    WHERE 1=(
          SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM Table T2 
          WHERE T1.ID=T2.ID AND T2.AS_OF>=T1.AS_OF
    )
```

This might also work..